# Nand Flash; MTD; UBI; Total Space

Tags: linux, mount, disk-usage

My question should stem from my misunderstanding of `ubi` and `MTD`. However, I can't figure it out by googling (And didn't find a good tutorial).

I simply want to find out the total capacity of my Nand Flashes, so I used `df -h`

```
    Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on             
    ubi0:rootfs               1.8G     46.8M      1.8G   3% /                      
    devtmpfs                375.4M         0    375.4M   0% /dev                   
    tmpfs                   503.5M         0    503.5M   0% /dev/shm               
    tmpfs                   503.5M    436.0K    503.1M   0% /tmp                   
    /dev/ubi0_0               1.8G     46.8M      1.8G   3% /mnt/nand
```

So far so good, It seems that my device has 2 nands: `ubi0_0` and `ubi0:rootfs` around `4 G` in total **(am I right ?)**

As far as I know, `UBIFS` is a filesytem for use on top of `MTD`; hence when I run `mtdinfo -a`, I should be able to see the `mtd` devices info and capacity. **My problem is, I have 4 `MTD` devices with total capacity of in order `2 GB` (mostly from `mtd0`). Why `df -h` shows me `2 * 1.8 GB` but `mtdinfo` shows `2 GB`** :

```
# mtdinfo -a                                                                   
Count of MTD devices:           4                                              
Present MTD devices:            mtd0, mtd1, mtd2, mtd3                         
Sysfs interface supported:      yes                                            

mtd0                                                                           
Name:                           gpmi-nand                                      
Type:                           nand                                           
Eraseblock size:                524288 bytes, 512.0 KiB                        
Amount of eraseblocks:          4096 (2147483648 bytes, 2.0 GiB)               
Minimum input/output unit size: 4096 bytes                                     
Sub-page size:                  4096 bytes                                     
OOB size:                       224 bytes                                      
Character device major/minor:   90:0                                           
Bad blocks are allowed:         true                                           
Device is writable:             true                                           

mtd1                                                                           
Name:                           U-Boot                                         
Type:                           nor                                            
Eraseblock size:                65536 bytes, 64.0 KiB                          
Amount of eraseblocks:          12 (786432 bytes, 768.0 KiB)                   
Minimum input/output unit size: 1 byte                                         
Sub-page size:                  1 byte                                         
Character device major/minor:   90:2                                           
Bad blocks are allowed:         false                                          
Device is writable:             false                                          

mtd2                                                                           
Name:                           env                                            
Type:                           nor                                            
Eraseblock size:                65536 bytes, 64.0 KiB                          
Amount of eraseblocks:          1 (65536 bytes, 64.0 KiB)                      
Minimum input/output unit size: 1 byte                                         
Sub-page size:                  1 byte                                         
Character device major/minor:   90:4                                           
Bad blocks are allowed:         false                                          
Device is writable:             false                                          

mtd3                                                                           
Name:                           Kernel                                         
Type:                           nor                                            
Eraseblock size:                65536 bytes, 64.0 KiB                          
Amount of eraseblocks:          114 (7471104 bytes, 7.1 MiB)                   
Minimum input/output unit size: 1 byte                                         
Sub-page size:                  1 byte                                         
Character device major/minor:   90:6                                           
Bad blocks are allowed:         false                                          
Device is writable:             true                                           

#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gpmi-nand` device seems to be mounted twice, as `/` and `/mnt/nand`. You can verify this by creating a file in `/root`; it should also appear in `/mnt/nand/root`... So you effectively only have one 2GB partition mounted, which matches `mtdinfo`'s output.

Comment: Thx. Do you know any good document/website about "MTD", "UBI", and in general how to associate them together.

Comment: I only know the [UBI FAQ and Howto](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/ubi.html)...

Comment: I read it, but I need something more in depth and more understandable for rookies like me :) Thx

Comment: FYI, I haven’t been chasing *you* in the Suggested Edits review queue; I’ve been chasing my fifth Steward badge. I’ve got it now, so the queue is all yours.